# Full gc or young gc from this gc log?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I test java gc with macbook air, and got this gc log, but I don't know it's full gc or young gc with line 2 ?

```
[GC[DefNew: 7139K->146K(9216K), 0.0109670 secs] 7711K->6862K(19456K), 0.0109990 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
[GC[DefNew: 6377K->6377K(9216K), 0.0000150 secs][Tenured: 6715K->8763K(10240K), 0.0094290 secs] 13093K->12988K(19456K), [Perm : 3441K->3441K(21248K)], 0.0094930 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
```

vm options is below :

```
-Xms20M -Xmx20M -Xmn10M -XX:+UseSerialGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails
```

and my test source code :

```
    byte[] b1 = new byte[2 * 1024 * 1024];
    byte[] b2 = new byte[2 * 1024 * 1024];
    byte[] b3 = new byte[2 * 1024 * 1024];

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println("after sleep 3 sec");

    byte[] b4 = new byte[2 * 1024 * 1024];
    System.out.println("after b4");

    byte[] b5 = new byte[2 * 1024 * 1024];
    byte[] b6 = new byte[2 * 1024 * 1024];
    System.out.println("after b6");
    /**
     *
     */
    byte[] b7 = new byte[2 * 1024 * 1024];

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println("end");
```

Thanks ahead.

**EDIT**

I get some information from this [link](https://plumbr.eu/handbook/garbage-collection-algorithms-implementations)

Comment: add `-XX:+PrintGCCause`

Answer (score 1):

> DefNew

That's the serial new gen collector. Thus it's a minor GC.

You may want to use [GCViewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer) to visualize GC logs.

Comment: But `Tenured ` and `Perm` collection happens in sencond line.